# Groupby Product and Time and include zeros

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID     Product     Time
C561   PX          2017-01-01 
                   00:00:00
T801   PT          2017-01-01
                   00:00:01
```

I already transformed the time format into months for better handling using this code:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.to_period("M")
```

Then I wanted to count the number of IDs for a particular product per month and wrote this code:

```
df=df.groupby(['Time','Product'])['ID'].size().reset_index()
```

This resulted in a dataframe like this:

```
Time     Product   ID
01-2017  PX        2
02-2017  PX        3
02-2017  PT        2
```

What I would now like to add are rows for products that do not have any IDs in a particular months. So I would want to add 0s for that, e.g.:

```
Time     Product   ID
01-2017  PX        2
01-2017  PT        0
02-2017  PX        3
02-2017  PT        2
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `unstack` and fill zeroes with `fill_value=0`, afterwards you can use `stack` again

```
df = df.groupby(['Time','Product'])['ID'].count().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.from_product()` to create new index then `.reimdex()` and `.fillna(0)`

```
 n= pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df.Time.unique(),\
df.Product.unique()), names=["Time", "Product"])



 df=df.set_index(["Time", "Product"]).reindex(n).fillna(0).reset_index()
print(df)




   Time   Product  ID
0  01-2017      PX  2.0
1  01-2017      PT  0.0
2  02-2017      PX  3.0
3  02-2017      PT  2.0
```